# Convert json file into labels.csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `labels.json` file containing the image name and ground truth value. Due to the changing in library I have to modify my data inside `json` file

**Inside Json**

```
{"자랑스럽다_2730052.jpg": "자랑스럽다", "만족스럽다_1299150.jpg": "만족스럽다"}
```

I want to generate a `labels.csv` file that contains the `filename` column and `words` columns and the format of `labels.csv`like below.

```
filename        words
2730052.jpg     자랑스럽다
```

**How I can do it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dict like `{colname:[...]}` and turn it to dataframe, replace text by `r'.+_'` then save to csv file.

```py
json = {"자랑스럽다_2730052.jpg": "자랑스럽다", "만족스럽다_1299150.jpg": "만족스럽다"}
df = pd.DataFrame({'filname': json.keys(), 'words': json.values()})
df['filname'] = df['filname'].replace(r'.+_', '', regex=True)
df.to_csv('labels.csv', index=False)
```

df:

```
       filname  words
0  2730052.jpg  자랑스럽다
1  1299150.jpg  만족스럽다
```